# Scrapy extract all text into one cell how to divide?

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to scrape some tweets but when i do in scrapy all tweets goes into 1 cell in csv file. How can i make it extract each tweet into 1 individual cell !

[image: excel sheet output from scrapy]

my code is:

```
class tiktokSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'twitter'
allowed_domains = ['twitter.com']
start_urls = ['http://twitter.com/']
allowed_domains = ['app.scrapingbee.com']
custom_settings = {'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 10}
custom_settings = {'FEEDS':{'poststoday.csv':{'format':'csv'}}}

def start_requests(self):
    for username in user_accounts:
        url = f'https://app.scrapingbee.com/api/v1/?api_key=hiddenkey&url=https://twitter.com/{username}&js_scroll=true&js_scroll_count=3&premium_proxy=true&country_code=us'
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
    def parse(self, response):
    items = TwitterproItem()
    full_name = response.css('.r-135wba7.r-1udh08x .r-qvutc0 .r-qvutc0::text').extract()
    tweet_text = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"css-901oao r-18jsvk2")]//text()').extract()
    items['full_name'] = full_name
    items['tweet_text'] = tweet_text

    yield items
```

any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Have you completed the [scrapy tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)? Can you share with us your complete spider, including the url you are trying to scrape?

Comment: i have completed it and i made few small projects and i never had this problem and i will edit my post now

Answer (score 0):

First, check the values of full_name and tweet_text using  `self.logger.info(full_name)`,

If full_name is a list then replace :

```
items['full_name'] = full_name
items['tweet_text'] = tweet_text
yield items
```

with :

```
for (name, text) in zip(full_name, tweet_text):
    item['full_name'] = name
    item['tweet_text] = text
    yield item
```